# What is the period of $f(x) = x^x \pmod n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

For $n = 2$, $f(x)$ is the sequence $1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, \ldots$ (period $2$). For $n = 3$, $f(x)$ is the sequence $1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, \ldots$ (period $6$). For $n = 4$, $1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1,\ldots$ (period $4$).

What is the period $P(n)$ of an arbitrary $n$?

Comment: Wouldn't the behavior be qualitatively different in general depending on which part of the domain we are in: $x^x > n$ or $x^x<n$? Or when you say period, do you mean for all $x \ge x_0$ for some $x_0$?

Answer (score 1):

[OEIS sequence A174824](http://oeis.org/A174824)

Suppose $n = \prod_{j=1}^k p_j^{d_j}$ is the prime factorization of $n$.

If $p_j$ divides $x$, then $x^x \equiv 0 \mod p_j^{d_j}$ as long as $x > d_j$.
If $p_j$ does not divide $x$, and $x \equiv b \mod p_j^{d_j}$ while $x \equiv c \mod \phi(p_j^{d_j}) = (p_j-1) p_j^{d_j-1}$, then $x^x \equiv b^x \equiv b^c \mod p_j^{d_j}$.  Thus $x^x \mod p_j^{d_j}$ is eventually periodic with period $\text{lcm}(p_j^{d_j}, (p_j-1) p_j^{d_j-1}) = (p_j-1) p_j^{d_j} $.  Using the Chinese remainder theorem, $x^x \mod n$ is eventually periodic with  period $\text{lcm}(n,  p_1 - 1, \ldots, p_k - 1)$.